# I want to make a registration form but the script wont work the way i want

Tags: javascript

To validate  the checkpoint the form will have to show an alert if

- One of the inputs is empty
- The password has less than 8 characters
- Doesn't have a valid e-mail adress
- The password must be a combination of charatacters , numbers and at least        a capital letter
- And finally the reset button will reset all the inputs to empty :

  ```
  //Variable declaration

  var username=document.forms["Registration"]["name"];
  var e_mail=document.forms["Registration"]["email"];
  var password=document.forms["Registration"]["psw1"];
  var passwordcheck=document.forms["Registration"]["psw2"];

  //add eventListener
  username.addEventListener("blur", NameVerify, true);
  e_mail.addEventListener("blur", EmailVerify, true);
  password.addEventListener("blur", PasswordVerify, true);
  passwordcheck.addEventListener("blur", PasswordVerify, true);

  // validate the registration   
  function Validate(){
      if (username.value=="")
      {
          alert("username is required");
          username.focus()
          return false;
      }
      if (e_mail.value=="")
      { 
         alert("Email is required");
         e_mail.focus()
         return false;
      }
      if (password.value=="")
      {
         alert("Password is required");
         password.focus()
         return false;
      }
      if (passwordcheck.value=="")
      {    
         alert("Re-enter your password");
         passwordcheck.focus()
         return false;
      }
      if(password.value != passwordcheck.value){
        alert("Password do not match!!")
        passwordcheck.focus()
        return false;
      }
  }

  //check the username value
  function NameVerify(username){
      if (username.value !=0) {
          document.querySelector.backgroundColor = lightGrey;
          return true;
      }
  }

  //check the e_mail
  function EmailVerify(e_mail){          
      if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.`\w{2,3})+$/.test(Registration.email.value))`
      {
           return (true)
      }
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
      e_mail.focus()
      return (false)
  }

  //check the password
  function PasswordVerify(password){
      var psw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,20}$/;

      if(password.value.match(psw)) 
      { 
           alert('Correct, try another...')
           return true;
      }
      else
      { 
           alert('Wrong!!')
           return false;
      }        
  }

  // clear all text inputs when the page is loaded
  function clearInp() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("input").value = "";
      return true;
  }

  //reset all text fields
  function Reset() {
      document.querySelector("#Registration").reset();
      return true;
  }
  ```

Comment: What exactly is not working with you code?

Comment: The check of the password wont work

Answer (score 1):

None of this requires any JavaScript at all.

- One of the inputs is empty

```
<input type="text" required />
```

- The password has less than 8 characters

```
<input type="password" minlength="8" />
```

- Doesn't have a valid e-mail adress

```
<input type="email" />
```

- The password must be a combination of charatacters , numbers and at least a capital letter

```
<input type="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}" />
```

- And finally the reset button will reset all the inputs to empty

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
```

Once you've eliminated all JavaScript code from your form, you will find that your form no longer has any JavaScript errors ;)

Comment: yeah i know but i want to do all the checks using JS

Comment: Why? Why would you want that?

Comment: my task is to build a registration form using JavaScript

Comment: A "task" should not tell you how to do it. A "task" should be something like building a registration form. Exactly how that form is built should be up to you, the developer. It is your job, as the developer, to figure out the details. It is not the job of whoever assigned the task to require that it be done in JavaScript, especially when JS is objectively the "wrong" way to do it.